# How to get all the database name in Amazon Redshift cluster

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, odbc, amazon-redshift

I need to get all the database which are present in Amazon Redshift cluster through Redshift ODBC driver. For this, I have used the below connection string and query,

```
ConnectionString:“Driver={Amazon Redshift (x64)}; Server=servername; UID=master; PWD=password; Port=5439”
```

**Query:**"Select * from pg_database".

When execute this query i got the error message like "ERROR [08001] [Amazon][ODBC] (10380) Unable to establish connection with data source. Missing settings: {[Database]}"

Can anyone please suggest me to overcome this error to get all databases.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try referencing the [specific column names](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/catalog-pg-database.html) that you need, rather than `SELECT *`.

Comment: You must include the database name in your connection settings. Once you have the database name, you can connect and query the pg_database table which is shared across all the databases. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/catalog-pg-database.html

Comment: Thank you....but i need to get all the databases in the case when i am not knowing the database name in listed databases in the cluster.